# Excluding scraped results that aren't of a specific format using string operations or regex

Tags: python, regex, if-statement, beautifulsoup

Hi I am developing a program that is scraping songs form a website and putting them into a list.  This is my code so far

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
from collections import namedtuple

url='http://www.xpn.org/playlists/xpn-playlist'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

songs=[]
Song = namedtuple("Song", "artist name album")
for link in soup.find_all("li", class_="song"):
    song = Song._make(link.text.strip()[12:].split(" - "))
    songs.append(song)

for song in songs:
    print(song.artist, song.name, song.album)
```

It works well if the results are of the format

```
<li class="song"> <a href="/default.htm" onclick="return clickreturnvalue()" onmouseover="dropdownmenu(this, event, menu1, '100px','Jason &amp; The Scorchers','I Really Don\'t Want To Know','Lost &amp; Found')" onmouseout="delayhidemenu()">Buy</a>  Jason &amp; The Scorchers - I Really Don't Want To Know - Lost &amp; Found</li>
```

But doesn't work if the results are of the format.

```
<li class="song">|World Cafe| - Thursday 10-22-2015 Hour 2, Part 7 - Host: David Dye</li>
```

I get an error because there are only two " - "

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-1a0a99934b5c> in <module>()
     12 Song = namedtuple("Song", "artist name album")
     13 for link in soup.find_all("li", class_="song"):
---> 14     song = Song._make(link.text.strip()[12:].split(" - "))
     15     songs.append(song)
     16 

<string> in _make(cls, iterable, new, len)

TypeError: Expected 3 arguments, got 2
```

How do I modify this to exclude any results that aren't of the correct format?

Comment: Your `namedtuple` is being **forced** to be populated with list has more than three element!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you try `namedtuple`-Below code worked for me.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from collections import namedtuple

url='http://www.xpn.org/playlists/xpn-playlist'
page = requests.get(url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

songs=[]
Song = namedtuple("Song", ["artist", "name", "album"])
for link in soup.find_all("li", class_="song"):
    data = map(unicode.strip,link.text.replace('Buy','').strip().split(" - "))
    if len(data)==3:
        song = Song._make(data)
        #print data
        songs.append(song)
    else:
        print "More than 3 item found"
for song in songs:
    print(song.artist, song.name, song.album)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a check to see if you are actually getting all three arguments that you want. If you just want to exclude results that aren't three arguments though, just have a try/except TypeError block.

```
def threeArgs(one, two, three):
    # function stuff

try:
    threeArgs(1, 2)
except TypeError:
    print "Skipping..."
```

This will not have an error, and will just skip and continue if put in your for loop.